# unfamiliar port forwarding command

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I recently came across the snippet below.

`ssh root@myserver.com -L <some_ip>:2182:127.0.0.1:2181`

I thought I had passing familiarity with port forwarding, but the presence of `<some_ip>` is throwing me for a loop here. Could someone more experienced please walk me through *exactly* what this code is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typical local portforwarding which will listen on `<some_ip>:2182` on the local machine and forward received traffic to `127.0.0.1:2181` on the remote machine.  While the local IP address to which to bind is commonly left unspecified (defaulting to `localhost`), it may be explicitly given if you wish to listen on a *particular* interface.

From [`man ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> **-L** [*bind_address*:]*port*:*host*:*hostport*
>
> **-L** [*bind_address*:]*port*:*remote_socket*
>
> **-L** *local_socket*:*host*:*hostport*
>
> **-L** *local_socket*:*remote_socket*
>
> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on 
>   the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and
>   port, or Unix socket, on the remote side. This works by allocating a
>   socket to listen to either a TCP *port* on the local side, optionally
>   bound to the specified *bind_address*, or to a Unix socket. Whenever a
>   connection is made to the local port or socket, the connection is
>   forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to either
>   *host* port *hostport*, or the Unix socket *remote_socket*, from the remote
>   machine.
>
> Port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file. Only the superuser can forward privileged ports. IPv6 addresses can be
>   specified by enclosing the address in square brackets.
>
> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the **GatewayPorts** setting. However, an explicit *bind_address* may be used to
>   bind the connection to a specific address. The *bind_address* of
>   “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use
>   only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates that the port should be
>   available from all interfaces.

Answer (score -2):

You need (e.g.) SSH port forwarding if the target address cannot be reached directly because it is a private address, localhost or behind a firewall.